# Looks like angularjs doesn't take interpolated value by the time of the click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

In a partial, I've got this local model, as follows:

```
<div ng-init="hotspots = [  
    {id:'a',    name:'litSemenceIdeal',         center: {x: 80, y:640}, photos:['1-LitDeSemence']},
    {id:'b',    name:'typeImplantation',        center: {x:232, y:503}, photos:['1-SemoirMonograineEcartementClassique']},
]"></div>
```

Which is used to build likable hotspots over a photo, with the following HTML:

```
<figure class="svg">

    <div 
        ng-repeat="hs in hotspots"
        style="left:{{hs.center.x}}px; top:{{hs.center.y}}px"
        oonclick="javascript:openPopover($('#{{hs.name}}'))"
        ng-click="openPopover('#{{hs.name}}')"
        >
        {{hs.id}}
    </div>

</figure>
```

Unfortunately enough, though I see the interpolated value in the Safari inspector, the scope openPopover() function does get the interpolated string as parameter when clicked.

Q1) How it comes I have this kind of difference between actual code and actual behavior? What to do to marshall everything?

EDIT 1: As suggested in the comments, I had left the {{}} which prevent angularjs to evaluate.

Q2) I've modified my code as follows (now that works):

```
        ng-click="openPopover('#'+hs.name+'')"
```

But, the resulting syntax omits the single quote around the hs.name. I previously tried this:

```
        ng-click="openPopover(\"'#\"+hs.name+\"'\")"
```

Without success.

Any idea?

Comment: It should be `openPopover(hs.name)`. ng-click take expression, you do not provide interpolation.

Comment: lol, you're right, a rotten copy and paste :-/ Write an answer for th